# Не работает пример из учебника

Tags: c

В книжке опубликовано, что в языке программирования СИ - "**Имя массива - это то же самое что и адрес его первого элемента**" и дан пример ниже:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
  char array[5];

  printf("   array = %p\n&array[0] = %p\n", array, array[0]);

}
```

У меня совершенно разные адреса выводятся. В чём ошибка, или это зависит от компилятора.
Задание выполнено на Win 7 x64, DevC++

Comment: Спасибо перекиньте в ответ, я закрою.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Символ '&' (это значит, адрес) перед `array[0]` добавьте.